# How do I round millions in Flutter? Example '29,971,800' to '30,00,000'

Tags: flutter, dart

Given a value example: 29971800.0 & I format it using NumberFormat.decimalPattern() so I got '29,971,800'. The problem is I want to round it to get the value of '30,000,000' instead of '29,971,800' or other example I want to round '356,740,000' to '357,000,000'.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Before you format round it using `num.round()` for example if you want to round to millions

```
double n = 29971800;
double roundTo = 1000000; //million
print((n/roundTo).round()); //prints 30
```

you can either multiply it by million and format it or just convert to `String` and add `',000,000'`